# get array elements which have key in second array in php

Tags: php, arrays, key, array-intersect

I need only array elements which have their keys in values of second array, *with the fastest script*.

```
$array_1 = array(
    'ana' => 'are',
    'du'  => 34,
    'bopq'=> "Ana are mere mereu",
    13    => "OK"
);

$array_2 = array('du', 13);

$expected_array = array(
    'du' => 34,
    13   => "OK"
);
```

There is faster solution than:

```
$expected_array = array_intersect($array_1, array_combine($array_2, $array_2);
```

?

Comment: So write some code and test. After that you can provide test results.

Comment: Show us your best effort and where you're stuck, so we can help you on your way.

Comment: You will have to loop over all array keys to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) is what you are looking for.

```
$array_1 = array(
    'ana' => 'are',
    'du'  => 34,
    'bopq'=> "Ana are mere mereu",
    13    => "OK"
);

$array_2 = array('du', 13);

$result = array_intersect_key($array_1, array_flip($array_2));
```

https://3v4l.org/P6jkq

Comment: Is the fastest from these 3 solutions we have here.